# Motion detect from voice

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, motion

Does anyone know a mature AI model either paid or open source which can detect the motions from a recorded voice? There are a few good ones for text but haven't seen acceptable ones for voice yet.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?